# Scala Try - Should this not result in a Failure?

Tags: scala, try-catch

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val line: List[String] = null
val myTry = Try(line.asJava)

val result = myTry match {
  case Success(_) => "Success"
  case Failure(_) => "Failure"
}

println(result)
```

This code snippet prints "Success". If I try to access `myTry.get`, then it throws a `NullPointerException`.

From how I understand Try, shouldn't myTry be a Failure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From how I understand Try, shouldn't myTry be a Failure?

Specifically, `asJava` on a `List` creates a wrapper around the original collection in the form of a `SeqWrapper`. It doesn't iterate the original collection:

```
case class SeqWrapper[A](underlying: Seq[A]) extends ju.AbstractList[A] with IterableWrapperTrait[A] {
    def get(i: Int) = underlying(i)
}
```

If you use anything else that does iterate the collection or tries to access it, like `toSeq`, you'll see the failure:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val line: List[String] = null
val myTry = Try(line.toSeq)

val result = myTry match {
  case Success(_) => "Success"
  case Failure(_) => "Failure"
}

println(result)
```

Comment: Interesting. According to http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html this is the case.

Sadly, I was depending on the behavior of either null converting to null, or failing to convert and immediately throwing an exception, which would result in a Failure.

Now it looks like I will have to explicitly check for null, as opposed to using a Try.

Comment: @Leumash Why not work with an `Option[List[String]]` instead?

Comment: Because Option[List[String]] would behave in the same way as Try. `Option(line.asJava).isDefined == true`. I ended up matching line to `case null => null` and `case _ => line.asJava`.

Comment: But then the `Option[T]` would be `None`, not `null`, and you won't be depending on `NullReferenceException`, as you wouldn't need a `Try[T]` at all. You'd only need `line.map { x => // stuff }`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous comment, I meant Option(line.asJava) is a Some.

Comment: @Leumash It is, but I'm not sure I understand you'd want `Option(line.asJava)`.

Comment: So just do `Option(line).map(_.asJava)`.  Problem solved.